# Using user's dir to store copied python3 packages

Tags: python-3.x

I'm defining an update procedure on the air-gapped standalone RedHat7 server with the preinstalled python3 and
basic packages.

The python3 applications are developed on a host with an Internet access, and are delivered to this standalone
server using DOK.
Additional packages can't be installed using pip, but must be trasfered from development host to the local user's home directory.

I'm looking for a proper way to update and activate python3 applications on this standalone server, without appending a new package path using sys.path.append("/home/user/packages/pack_N") before importing it.

Thanks

Zeev

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you meant without using "PyPi".

Downloading the packages can be done with `pip wheel <package>` after installing the wheel package.

Installing them locally without using pip's servers (PyPi) can be done like so:

`pip install <package> --no-index --find-links=<directory containing wheels>`

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the response.
There are some limitations that prevent such a solution ...
The user's home directory resides on the central storage, which is accessible to a  number of standalone servers.
The new packages must be added to this user's home dir, to be accessible when the Python applications are activated.

Comment: How about changing PYTHONPATH?

Comment: By default, all the basic and afterward installed packages reside at /usr/local/python3.N/lib/site-packages. I've tried the recommended solution with PYTHONPATH that is set to /home/myuser/lib, where the new packages are copied. It worked well with the "cryptography" and "json2xml" packages, but when I've copied the "requests" one, the 'import" failed for some modules located in the 'requests" folder.